# Conditionally appending to parent using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
function updateList (day,bt) {
    $.getJSON('index.php?task='+((bt==1)?'getSubmit':'getReceive'),{day:day}, function(data) {
        var $day=$("#todays").empty();
        if(data.length>0) {
            $.each(data, function( i, v ) {
                console.log(v)
                $('<a/>', {
                    href    :'index.php?id='+v['id'],
                    'class' :'linkPreview',
                    title   :'Get Results',
                    text    :v['name']
                })
                .append(bt==1?'':$('<span>'+formatExtra(v.title,v.number)+'</span>'))
                .wrap('<li'+((v['user']==1)?' class="users"':'')+'>').parent().appendTo('#todays');
            });
            $day.find('li:even').addClass('alt');
            $day.find('a.linkPreview').ajaxTip(ayb.linkPreviewObj);
        }
        else {
            $day.html('<li class="no-none">You have no data today</li>');
        }
    });
}
```

I am trying to create:

```
<ul id="todays" class="list">
    <li class="users alt">
        <a title="Get Results" class="linkPreview" href="index.php?id=5">
            <span>Main Stuff</span>
        </a>
        <span>Extra Stuff</span>
    </li>
    <!-- more list elements .... -->
</ul>
```

Instead, I am creating:

```
<ul id="todays" class="list">
    <li class="users-bids alt">
        <a title="Get Results" class="linkPreview" href="index.php?id=5">
            <span>Main Stuff
                <span>Extra Stuff</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- more list elements .... -->
</ul>
```

I think my problem is this line:

```
.append(bt==1?'':$('<span>'+formatExtra(v.title,v.number)+'</span>'))
```

I am appending the `<span>` to the `<span>` element in the `<a>` element, and not to the `<a>` as I desire.

See http://jsfiddle.net/95ztrmk3/1/ for the condition that doesn't work, and http://jsfiddle.net/95ztrmk3 for the condition that does work (note that I simplified it a bit, but the intent is the same).

How can I conditionally append an element to parent?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but maybe you could try appending to `<li class="users alt">` instead.

Comment: @alex.  I can change it to `.appendTo(bt==1?'':$('<span>'+formatExtra(v.title,v.number)+'</span>')).parent()`, but it only works this time when bt is zero.  The previous version only works when bt is 1.

Comment: I think you have the answer to your own question: you use the .append() or .appendTo() functions after selecting an element's parent.  In _this_ particular context, I'm having a hard time seeing what's going on.  Could you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: @alex.  http://jsfiddle.net/95ztrmk3/ using the first way.  Try changing the bt value from 1 to something else, and you will see the problem.